# How to make encrypted volume that will work like an ID Challenge

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I want to make an encrypted volume where the "master password" de-crypts the volume but there is also an "ID Challenge" password which will open an empty volume.
To explain better, suppose I'm held at gunpoint, instead of not giving up my password and getting shot, I can give a "fake password" which will only seem to open the volume but in reality it opened up a failsafe volume which has non-sensitive data. So the bad guy believes I gave him the correct password but at the same time the real volume was not de-crypted. 
I know TrueCrypt had something similar but since it's no longer supported I'm looking for a more secure and supported software.

EDIT: If there is a way to do this without using 3rd party software, that would help too.

Comment: You're looking for hidden volumes. Requests for products are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). If you go for this kind of setup, don't forget to regularly use the "fake" volume.

Comment: Support is irrelevant. TrueCrypt can do that. So does Veracrypt (it's follower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think, there is no good way to implement such a system.

An encrypted volume will always be visible on disk as an area of highly random data (as that is what encryption does) and always raise suspicion to someone looking for encrypted data. There is no way to 
hide that fact reliably.

There are "headerless" encryption formats (like dm-crypt without LUKS on Linux) that hide **how** the disk is encrypted from the attacker, but that is as good as it gets.

In the end it will always boil down to convincing your attacker, that you really given them all there is. Deniable encryption is just as vulnerable against [rubber-hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption#Drawbacks) as "normal" encryption.

To quote Wikipedia on the [Drawbacks of Deniable Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption#Drawbacks):

> Deniable encryption has been criticized because it does not defend
>   users from revealing keys under coercion or torture. Possession of
>   deniable encryption tools could lead attackers to continue torturing a
>   user even after the user has revealed all his keys, because the
>   attackers could not know whether the user had revealed his last key or
>   not.

You will be much better off by increasing your security by investing in a hardware key token (e.g. a Yubikey) or by keeping your key on USB stick in form of a keyfile. That way you destroy them case of an emergency, making the data unrecoverable.

As long there is a way for you to recover the data and your attacker is informed/paranoid enough to look for it, you will always run the risk of being pressured to reveal it.

Comment: Is there a way, when I give the attacker a  "fake" password, it self destructs the data on the drive to show that the drive is actually empty